# Copyright IP of own effort and the boundaries of "Capital asset" in IRS tax law, wrt. donations

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, tax-law, non-profit

In ["Instructions for Form 8283"](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8283.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, it says you can donate and deduct:

> **Intellectual property.** The FMV of intellectual property
>   must be reduced to figure the amount of your deduction,
>   as explained earlier. Intellectual property means a patent,
>   copyright (other than a copyright described in section
>   1221(a)(3) or 1231(b)(1)(C)), trademark, trade name,
>   trade secret, know-how, software (other than software
>   described in section 197(e)(3)(A)(i)), or similar property,
>   or applications or registrations of such property.

In [section 1221(a)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1221) of U.S. Code § 1221 - Capital asset defined (extra bold/emphasis mine):

> (a) **IN GENERAL** For purposes of this subtitle, the term “capital asset” means property held by the taxpayer (whether or not connected with his trade or business), but **does not include**—
>
> - (3) a **copyright**, a literary, musical, or artistic composition, a letter or memorandum, or similar property, **held by**—
>
>   - (A) a **taxpayer** whose **personal efforts created** such property,
>   - (B) in the case of a letter, memorandum, or similar property, a taxpayer for whom such property was prepared or produced, or
>   - (C) **a taxpayer in whose hands the basis of such property is determined, for purposes of determining gain from a sale or exchange, in whole or part by reference to the basis of such property in the hands of a taxpayer described in subparagraph (A) or (B)**;

My question is about section 1221(a)(3)(C); my understanding is that it is meant to prevent simply giving over an IP to a family member or friend, and thus bypass the condition of 1221(a)(3)(A): "a taxpayer whose personal efforts created such property" <sup>2</sup>. But I'm not sure what paragraph (C) actually *means*, and how it avoids this bypass. Specifically my question is to **explain this passage** ( 1221(a)(3)(C) ), and to explain **if it would apply** to say for example, if **two friends exchange IPs "of their own effort", in a barter exchange**, and then turn around and donate their newly owned assets.

---

- [1] [U.S. Code § 170 - Charitable, etc., contributions and gifts](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/170) - actual law this is derived from, AFAICT
- [2] I got this impression from [It Does Not Compute: Copyright Restriction on Tax Deduction for Developer's Donation of Software](http://www.pgdc.com/pdf/It_Does_Not_Compute.pdf):

  > [97] Rules are in place to prevent the creator from avoiding the section 170(e)(1)(A) restriction. If the creator gives the copyright or composition to a friend or family member (or anyone else), and the donee then makes a charitable contribution of the property, the donee's charitable income tax deduction will be restricted in the same way as if the creator had made the contribution